# MySQL upgrade version output seems odd

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I just upgraded my old MySQL instance to `5.7.31`.
When I do a

```
select version();
```

I get

```
5.7.31-log
```

I am used to seeing something like (on my older version)

```
5.5.2
```

What does the `-log` stand for in `5.7.31-log` and it is an issue of concern or just a change in how the version is outputted?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331746/what-does-log-stand-for-in-mysql-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing the version of MySQL, the value might also include a suffix indicating server build or configuration information.  A `-log` suffix indicates that one or more of the general log, slow query log, and/or binary log are enabled

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Not to worry.

Long answer:

I did a survey of over 200 MySQL and MariaDB version names -- 40% ended with -log.  They went back to version 4.1, perhaps farther.

(Interestingly, none of the 8.0 versions ended in -log.)

(I've been using MySQL for 20 years, and have never heard why some have "-log".  And I have not noticed a problem.)

For more trivia:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%';
```

Comment: Thank you...I haven’t noticed an issue yet either.